# Laravel 5. Dynamic data in app.blade.php: BaseController or ViewComposers?

Tags: php, laravel

I have my wrapping layout in app.blade.php and I need dynamic data for it, lets say a list of categories showing at the top of every view.

Following best practices, what would you do in Laravel 5?

1. To create a new Service Provider that loads a new View Composer and set the dynamic data for the view in the compose() method (as a newbie it looks like a lot of work for something this common)
2. To create a BaseController, set the dynamic data for the view form it and make every controller in my app to extend it.

I guess this is a very common scenario, Imagine for example something like `<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>` in app.blade.php that needs to be set on every controller. But I couldn't find the right way to do it so far.

Comment: I recommend a view composer. And it's not *that* much work ;)

Comment: Everyone recommends a view composer but if you do a search you will find literally tons of examples that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is just using

```
view()->share('title', "My Page");
```

This works in your routes.php, and several other files.

Using a view composer is also a great option though.